# How to parse site that is protected by DDOS Guard?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to parse a site, that is protected by DDOS Guard. Simple GET request in Python via `requests` module responses with 403 and `text` property of the response is HTML page, that reveals the presence of DDOS Guard. Is there any way to bypass that and go straight to the site, or DDOS-protected sites are un-parseable?

P. S. `allow_redirect` had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to emulate a real browser.